# Declaring a static object from inside its own class

Tags: c#, oop, static

Hi I have some code where I use a static object of Manager to call methods from Manager:

```
public class Manager
{
    public static Manager sManager = new Manager();
    public int x;

    public Manager()
    {  
    }


    public void Modify()
    {
        x ++;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Manager.sManager.x);
        Manager.sManager.Modify();
        Console.WriteLine(Manager.sManager.x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Is this a good way of accessing a method from Manager from outside or is there a better way if the class Manager must own the method Modify.

Would use of events in this case be a better way to build this and have Manager listen for an update?

Or is there a better way to handle this even if I want the method Modify to stay inside the Manager class?

Comment: It strikes me as though you should just instantiate the instance of `Manager` externally where you need it or make the whole class and all methods/properties static (if that works, I don't know the application)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. I agree with @JamesHughes that simply instantiating `Manager` is enough.

Comment: I may be wrong for this, but I see quite a few Java developers doing this. I don't see why this would be beneficial. If you want to do this, you may as well define the class as static.

Comment: it looks like a half done [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: yes that is exactly what it is

Comment: for a real singleton you would have a `private` constructor. Otherwise you allow for multiple instances to be created. so this is more of a *multiton* ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the architecture you're trying to build.

**Make everything static**

If it's as simple as that, just make `x` and `Modify` static and you won't need an instance.

**Use a singleton pattern**

If you do need a Manager instance your code would be better using a Singleton pattern

```
private static Manager _manager;

public static Manager Manager
{
   get 
   {
      if (_manager == null)
      {
         _manager = new Manager();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason here to create a static field of same type in the `Manager` class. You just need to create an object and then call the needed methods.

A more better way can be to make field private and just expose it for reading so that it can't be modified directly, and we only modify it by calling the `modify()` method:

```
public class Manager
{

  private int x;

  public int X
  {
    get
    {
       return x;
    }
  }

  public Manager()
  {  
  }


  public void Modify()
  {
      x++;
  }
}
```

and then in your Program class use it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Manager objManager = new  Manager();
        Console.WriteLine(objManager.X);

        objManager.Modify();

        Console.WriteLine(objManager.X);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```